# Amalur can't see saves after Origin update

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning, origin

I was happily merrily playing *Kingdoms of Amalur* until a recent Origin update. This update reseted *Amalur* settings and saves. Strangly, I can see saves on my hard drive just fine:

[image: saves on the disk].

How do I make *Amalur* see these saves?